# I have a checkbox inside a fragment and i want it to post some data on click of a register button this button is inside my main activity?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-checkbox

I am working for the 1st time in fragment...in main activity i have a spinnerListner and as the item changes in spinner, in fragment container... fragments changes accordingly and i have just created some checkboxes in fragment.xml files... i just want to post and store a different value "NameoftheCheckbox" for every checked checkbox and another valuelike"Null" for every unchecked checkbox(even from the fragments which is not showing in container) on every registration click. like the way i am trying to store name and pin through RegisterUser function in my main activity...

My MainActivity

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText et_Name, et_Pin;
    private Button RegisterBTN;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private CheckBox checka, checkb;

    private Spinner sDropdown;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        et_Pin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPin);

        checka = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_a);


        RegisterBTN = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Reg);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        //progressDialog.setMessage();

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinnerListner();

        RegisterBTN.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void spinnerListner(){
        sDropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        sDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        switch (position){
                            case 0:
                               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag, Info_frag.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag, Plumber_frag.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag, Painter_frag.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag, Electrician_frag.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"F3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }

                        /**
                         * TextView spinnerDailogText = (TextView)view;
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You selected:"+ spinnerDailogText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }


    private void registerUser(){
        final String name = et_Name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String pin = et_Pin.getText().toString().trim();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.REGISTER,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("reg_name", name);
                params.put("reg_pin", pin);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == RegisterBTN);
            registerUser();

    }
}
```

My FragmentActivity

```js
public class Electrician_frag extends Fragment {

    public static Electrician_frag newInstance() {
        Electrician_frag fragment = new Electrician_frag();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Electrician_frag(){

    }

      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_electrician, container, false);
          return rootview;
    }

}
```

Another Fragment Activity

```js
public class Painter_frag extends Fragment {

    public static Painter_frag newInstance(){
        Painter_frag fragment = new Painter_frag();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Painter_frag(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_painter, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

My PainterFragment.xml

```js
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="124dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
            android:text="@string/a"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_y"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox_x"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox_x"
            android:text="@string/b"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: register clicklistener on getActivity().

Comment: You could try to add public getters to all your fragments `CheckBox`es and read their values in your `registerUser()`method.

Comment: Hi Jaydeep patel can you show me editing my code?

Comment: what is role of fragment in this?
you didn't mention any code in fragment.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel I am working for the 1st time in fragment... you can see in main activity i have a spinnerListner and as the item changes in spinner, in fragment container... fragments changes accordingly and i have just created some checkboes in fragmen xml file... i just want to post and store a different value "NameoftheCheckbox" for every checked checkbox and another value like"Null" for every unchecked checkbox on every registration click. like the way i am trying to store name and pin through RegisterUser function... Did You get it now? please help if possible.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel or i can say, it's a registration form and in spinner i have a list of categories and according to these categories... Using fragments i am showing sub categories and on registration function i want these checkboes to post some value like "if a is checked it will post A" and if not checked it'll post N.A. now you get it?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel Your reply?

Comment: @redead can show me editing my code?

Comment: what is inside of layout fragment_painter?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel what happened i have updated my painter layout xml code.